# Manipulate dynamically called array by way of pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, quicksort, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am building a quick sort function for a class i'm in, The functions involved are intended to sort the array by use of pointers, but I am having a hard time figuring out the right syntax for manipulating an array that was dynamically created. Here is the code snippet :

```
`/*
 * Dynamically allocates an array with the given capacity.
 * If a previous array had been allocated, delete the previous array.
 * Returns false if the given capacity is non-positive, true otherwise.
 *
 * @param
 *      size of array
 * @return
 *      true if the array was created, false otherwise
 */
 bool createArray(int capacity){
   if(capacity<0)return false;
   if(arrayP!=NULL){
   if(!arrayP.empty()){
     delete arrayP;
     arrayP= new int[capacity];
   }
  }
   arrayP= new int[capacity];
   return true;
 }`
```

Any information or resources on how to call functions on arrayP, and iterate through the array would be very helpful

Comment: What does "call functions on arrayP" mean? And how would you normally iterate through an array in C++?

Comment: It sounds like `createArray` should be a member of a class that manages the dynamic array.

Comment: Your specifications of the return value are different.

Comment: If `arrayP` is a pointer, then you cannot call a function `empty` on it.

Comment: @NeilKirk, is there anyway to access the array that is being pointed to? Something like arrayP->empty()?

Comment: Those arrays are dumb and don't know their size. You must store it separately or use a smarter container such as vector.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you're having problems with the following, which is not valid on an `int*`:

```
if( !arrayP.empty() ) ...
```

The correct approach, accepting that using raw pointers like this is not really the norm these days, is like this:

```
arrayP = new int [capacity];
```

That's *all* you do.  If you want to delete the old one (regardless of whether it's `nullptr` or not), you call:

```
delete [] arrayP;
```

Beyond that, you index into it just as you would an array:

```
for( int i = 0; i < capacity; i++ )
{
    arrayP[i] = 0;
}
```

Note that the above can also be achieved with:

```
std::fill( arrayP, arrayP + capacity, 0 );
```

Also, your function should really accept a `size_t` and use an assert to make sure it's non-zero.  No need to have a return value at all.  If allocation fails, `new []` will throw an exception.

```
void createArray( size_t capacity )
{
    assert( capacity > 0 );
    delete [] arrayP;
    arrayP = new int [capacity];
    arrayCapacity = capacity;     // <-- You really should remember this.
}
```

I'm gonna stop here, before this becomes too much like a code-review, and I start demanding that you use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`, and that the semantics of the name "create array" should actually assert-fail if already created.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, I wouldn't do it this way, but the class that contains this function is inherited from an interface file that I'm not allowed to change. They get pretty picky with how they want it done because it needs to work with their testing/grading system.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the array arrayP is pointing to is empty? something like arrayP->empty() ?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"?  It's just a block of memory.  It contains whatever was there before allocation, or after specific values were written to it.